# How to update this in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a value in a table row as given below:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Tutorialtwo/chapter_1b.png
```

I want to update the table so that it changes the above to this:

```
/storage/sdcard1/Tutorialtwo/chapter_1b.png
```

How do I do this in SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`substr`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

> substr(X,Y,Z), substr(X,Y)
>   The `substr(X,Y,Z)` function returns a substring of input string `X` that begins with the `Y`-th character and which is `Z` characters long. If `Z` is omitted then `substr(X,Y)` returns all characters through the end of the string `X` beginning with the `Y`-th.

to extract the `'/Tutorialtwo/chapter_1b.png'` suffix and then a string concatenation to put the new `'/storage/sdcard1'` prefix on. The SQL version would look something like this:

```
update t
set c = '/storage/sdcard1' || substr(c, 12)
where ...
```

where `t` is the table name and `c` is the column in question.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause ought to include `c LIKE '/mnt/sdcard/%'` for safety.